# Displaying the SKU in cart item names on WooCommerce cart page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, sku

I am showing SKU value with product title in cart page but right now each words SKU and product title getting linking separately.how can i show just single link rather then having linking separately.

for showing SKU value In cart page added this code in 
**Functions.php**

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'add_sku_in_cart', 20, 3);
function add_sku_in_cart( $title, $values, $cart_item_key ) {
$sku = $values['data']->get_sku();
$url = $values['data']->get_permalink( $product->ID );
$final='<a href="'. $url .'">SKU: '. $sku .'</a>';
return $title ?  sprintf("%s  - ", $final) .$title : $final;
}
```

> > Example
> >     Right now showing this
>
> ```
> <a href="http://localhost/test/?product=child-product">SKU: asda121 </a> - <a href="http://localhost/test/?product=child-product">Child Product</a>
> ```
>
> but I want it like that
>
> ```
> <a href="http://localhost/test/?product=child-product">SKU: asda121 - Child Product</a>
> ```

Comment: because $title is not inside the a tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use your custom function hooked in **`woocommerce_cart_item_name`** filter hook this way, to get the same link on both Sku and item name *(when sku exist)*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'customizing_cart_item_name', 10, 3 );
function customizing_cart_item_name( $item_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key  ) {

    $product = $cart_item['data'];
    $sku = $product->get_sku();

    // When sku doesn't exist
    if(empty($sku)) return $item_name;

    $product_name = $product->get_name();
    $product_id = $product->get_id();
    $url = $product->get_permalink( $product_id );

    return '<a href="'. $url .'">Sku: ' . $sku . ' - ' .$product_name . '<a>';
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

Tested and works

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'add_sku_in_cart', 20, 3);

function add_sku_in_cart( $title, $values, $cart_item_key ) {

    $sku = $values['data']->get_sku();
    $url = $values['data']->get_permalink( $product->ID );
    $final='SKU: '. $sku . ($title ? ' - ' . $title : '');
    return '<a href="'. $url .'">' . $final . '</a>';
}
```

Comment: i am still getting sku and product linking separately . i want to output  like <a href="">sku:121 - product name</a>

Comment: Can you paste the html code obtained for your link @Asher

Comment: Please check 
       <a href="http://localhost/test/?product=child-product">SKU: asda121 - </a><a href="http://localhost/test/?product=child-product">Child Product</a>

but i want output like 
<a href="http://localhost/test/?product=child-product">SKU: asda121 - Child Product</a>

Comment: you get this for the above lines of code that i gave?
    `$final='SKU: '. $sku . ($title ? $title : '');`
    `return '<a href="'. $url .'">' . $final . '</a>';`

Answer (score -1):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'add_sku_in_cart', 20, 3);
function add_sku_in_cart(){
global $woocommerce;
$items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
$product_names = array();

foreach($items as $item => $values) { 

    // Retrieve WC_Product object from the product-id:
    $_woo_product = wc_get_product( $values['product_id'] );

    // Get SKU from the WC_Product object:
    $product_names[] = $_woo_product->get_sku(); 
 }
}
```

Comment: please don't answer with code-only snippets, explain why your answer helps the user

Comment: User wants to display SKU value in cart page i have used filter hook which is used for adding content in cart page
using this line
$items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart(); we can get the product contents and using loop i can display sku value on specific location in cart page with product title. We have to add this function with hook in functions.php file so that for all products SKU value will be displayed with product title in cart page in woocommerce

Comment: for me this code is not working. can you please recheck it? i cant see anything in cart page